# MVC Ajax.Begin form isn't posting back to actionresult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax

I have recently changed the below code from using a regular html 'form' to using an ajax.beginform, but it does not post back to the 'PostCheckListCompleted' actionresult.  Any ideas why this is not working?

```
        @Html.Grid(Model.ContactApplicationConditionList).RowAttributes(row => new Hash(@class => row.Item.IsSatisfied ? "completeRow" : "incompleteRow")).Columns(c =>
        {
            c.For(a => string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", a.DateRequested)).Named("Date Requested");
            c.For(a => string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", a.DateDeadline)).Named("Deadline Date");
            c.For(a => string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", a.DateReceived)).Named("Date Received");
            c.For(a => a.Comment).Named("Comment");
            c.For(a => a.ApplicationOfferCondition.Name).Named("Checklist type");
            c.For(a => @Html.Raw(String.Format("<a href=\"#?w=380\" onclick=\"$('body').data('contactApplicationConditionId', '{0}' );\" rel=\"checklistUpdatePopup\" class=\"popupWindow\">Update</a>", a.ContactApplicationConditionId))).Named("Update");
            c.Custom(



                @<text>
                    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("PostCheckListCompleted", "Home", new AjaxOptions  { HttpMethod = "Post" }))
                    {
                        @Html.CheckBox("checkListCompleted", item.IsSatisfied, new { onclick = "$(this).parent('form:first').submit();" })
                        <input type="hidden" name="contactApplicationId" value=@ViewBag.ApplicationId />      
                        <input type="hidden" name="contactApplicationConditionId" value="@item.ContactApplicationConditionId" />     
                    }
                </text>

            ).Named("Complete");
        }).Attributes(@cellpadding => "0", @cellspacing => "0", @class => "table_results")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using firebug's XHR console to see what is returned by the action?

Comment: yes, but i'm not seeing any activity.  I've also tried testing it with a @Html.SubmitButton but nothing.  I'm sure it must be something simple, but can't see it :o).

Comment: Have you included the necessary javascript files?

Comment: Shouldn't the Ajax.BeginForm post to "PostCheckListAsync" rather than "PostCheckListCompleted"? Do you have both methods Async and Completed for Action?

Comment: Tim: Good question, but I know that the 'onclick = "$(this).parent('form:first').submit();"' works because I used it in a HTML.form before, so all the necessary files are included.  Also I have Ajax postbacks that are working in other partial views.

Comment: Kaps, 'PostCheckListCompleted' is the just name of the ActionResult method, but I don't have one called 'PostCheckListAsync'.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the jquery unobtrusive-ajax library to your page

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and change that code line with

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("PostCheckListCompleted", "Home", new AjaxOptions  { HttpMethod = "Post", Url = Url.Action("PostCheckListCompleted") }))
```

Check also if you want to set a target for ajax callback, setting the property UpdateTargetId of AjaxOptions

Answer (score -1):

Have you referenced ajax required script files?

Microsoft.Ajax.js
MicrosoftMvc.Ajax.js

and possibly jquery if required